# инструмент для построения диаграмм

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Есть приложение на ASP.NET MVC, работающее с БД (проект под Visual Studio 2010). Нужно визуализировать данные из БД в виде диаграммы. Использовали для этого jit.js, 
[ForceDirected](https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.html). Но эта диаграмма не устраивает заказчика. Нужно чтобы:

1. все элементы были в виде прямоугольников (с разным цветом границы в
   зависимости от значений);
2. данные были написаны внутри прямоугольников, а не рядом, и внутри можно было добавлять не только текст, но и рисунок;
3. связи между элементами были изображены в виде различных типов линий (сплошная, пунктирная, штрихпунктирная и т.п.) различного цвета;
4. элементы можно было передвинуть так,
   чтобы линии связи не пересекались и распечатать в таком же виде (с
   учетом того, как пользователь переместил объекты);
5. можно было щелкнув правой кнопкой по связи или элементе на диаграмме и
   связь/элемент удалялись с диаграммы (но не из базы) и при нажатии на
   кнопку печати там этого элемента тоже не было.

Т.е. чтобы была диаграмма, похожая на эту [image: диаграмма]
Существуют ли готовые библиотеки для построения таких диаграмм, и если нет, то в какую сторону смотреть при разработке собственной?

Comment: создать в dgml редакторе или прямо из кода (т.к. dgml - это xml), а показывать на странице как svg или gif. см. [тут](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46b71f5f-a4d5-4867-9d50-0416f7aefe28)

Comment: а под Visual Studio 2010 подобное есть?

Comment: dgml редактор есть даже в бесплатном VS Community 2015, а в VS 2010 не знаю. но если нет, то посмотрите [msagl](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/)

Comment: Посмотрите, есть ли что-то подходящее [среди примеров](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) D3js

Comment: @Stack, dgml с последующим экспортом в svg конечно в некоторых ситуациях полезен. Однако у автора задача состоит в том, что бы реализовать функционал по созданию и редактированию диаграмм вовсе не в визуал студии - ей нужно непосредственно в браузере клиента, налету. В противном случае она могла бы и тупо в Microsoft Visio диаграмму набросать, так же экспортировав результат в SVG/PNG - в VIsio инструментов и готовых элементов побольше будет, нежели в DGML-редакторе.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"реализовать функционал по созданию и редактированию диаграмм вовсе не в визуал студии"_ -- dgml - это обычный xml. для его создания VS не требуется.

Comment: @Stack, и? Для экспорта в SVG всё равно придется установить студию, поставить на неё расширение DgmlPowerTools, руками открыть dgml-файл в студии, и выбрать из меню File экспорт в SVG. Только толку то от этого? Это вовсе не вариант реализации редактирования диаграм в браузере. Или вы предлагаете всем клиентам поставить Visual Studio с вышеупомянутым расширением, а автору сделать страничку с кнопками "выгрузить dgml" и "загрузить svg-файл"?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"Для экспорта в SVG всё равно придется установить студию, поставить на неё расширение DgmlPowerTools"_ -- не надо ставить VS. DgmlPowerTools - это .net-сборка, ее классы можно использовать в своем приложении. но надо смотреть лицензию, возможно в коммерческом проекте это делать нельзя. _"вы предлагаете всем клиентам поставить Visual Studio"_ -- у вопроса указан тег asp.net -- это значит что на сервере работает .net и dgml можно и нужно конвертировать на сервере, а клиенты в своих браузерах получат или рис. или svg.

Comment: @Stack, вы увели вопрос в сторону - ваше решение всё равно не позволит редактировать диаграмму **прямо в браузере**. И да, просто так использовать это расширение в проекте ASP.NET, "выдав своё приложение за Visual Studio" не получится - у него есть прямые зависимости от кучи библиотек студии и COM-библиотек, требующих интерактивного режима работы Windows.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"вы увели вопрос в сторону - ваше решение всё равно не позволит"_ -- я написал в комментах два варианта. если у вас есть решение - напишите как ответ. или хотя бы свой вариант предложите. а когда на экране появится пара сотен объектов связанных линиями вспомните мои варианты. _"у него есть прямые зависимости от кучи библиотек"_ -- они нужны для интеграции пакета в VS. а для экспорта dgml они не нужны. ничего не мешает посмотреть как сделан экспорт.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [mxGraph](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/) либо [GoJS](http://gojs.net/latest/index.html). В частности, среди примеров GoJS есть [довольно схожий с вашей задачей](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html) - можете просто слегка подкорректировать то, что не понравится заказчику.